# Using MVP, who controls simple UI changes like image changes?

Tags: c#, mvp

I'm working with an MVP pattern, and am wondering who should be controlling simple UI changes such as adjustments to text or images.

For example, we have a screen that should change text and image when specific conditions are met. Assuming my data class looks like this :

```
pubilc class Data
{
    TypeEnum FormType { get; set; }
}
```

Should I be using:

```
public class Presenter
{
    void Presenter(Data data)
    {
        switch (data.FormType)
        {
            case TypeEnum.New:
                View.Image = NewImage;
                View.Title = "Create a new record";
                break;

            case TypeEnum.Delete:
                View.Image = DeleteImage;
                View.Title = "Delete an existing record";
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Or this:

```
public class Presenter
{
    void Presenter(Data data)
    {
        View.SetFormType = data.FormType;
    }   
}

public class View
{
    public void SetFormType(TypeEnum formType)
    {
        switch (formType)
        {
            case TypeEnum.New:
                Image = NewImage;
                Title = "Create a new record";
                break;

            case TypeEnum.Delete:
                Image = DeleteImage;
                Title = "Delete an existing record";
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

What determines which method is picked, and why?

Comment: I think it should be on https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.